# Read process memory strings like Process Hacker 2 in python

Tags: python, string, memory

I want to dump all the strings of a running process like Process Hacker 2 using python, with input is the pID and min length of the strings

[image]

I want to dump everything like this, but every documentations or videos I found were about game cheating and offsets... but that is not really what i need.
And also, this things seems to be useless to many people but for me, then please don't ask me why I do this
If you play Minecraft and like screenshare, you will understand what im trying to do.

Comment: The only documentation you will have is from game cheating, since very few other disciplines need to do such things. Next, you mention minecraft. **If you are trying to do something with minecraft, do not use process hacker.** Tell us what you're really trying to do, chances are you can use the Java Native Interface to do what you want.

Comment: umm actually, I'm not doing things with Minecraft. What other modules created seems to purpose of creating cheat software, what I'm doing is create things that can detect them. (a.k.a sstools ). Then, whenever people open an exe files, in window services such as DPS,CPASVC.... will save some basic information of the file (created time for example). I can create my self a tool that dump process strings, but I have no idea how PH2 can split strings into rows that is a big deal to me.

Answer (score 1):

`Process Hacker` and other tools extract strings from many places using heuristics.

Since you are trying to extract strings from a PE loaded in memory, you **must** play with offsets. In fact the tool, knowing how the internals are represented in memory (a.k.a. reading the specs and heavily reverse engineer the rest) can scan certain locations to extract few strings (function names, import libraries, ...). The rest is extracted with heuristics, that is, the heap memory is scanned and all the sequences of bytes satisfying certain requirements are assumed to be strings.

In my machine, i can very well see these strings from a silly C program, and none of them are truly strings in my code, but just random bytes that seem strings:

- `AAAZ@1`
- `ABCD`

Dumping strings from a native PE (no .NET or Java) requires reverse engineering, which is an art. The goal(s) you want to achieve dictates the means and constraints that you need to use for dumping the strings.

Since you are not telling us why you are doing this, we can only speculate that is to extract certain game related codes from memory. Now, if the strings you need are static and stored in PE itself, you can use [strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings) from *SysInternals*. Else, you need in-memory data dumping. Assuming there is no protection at all, you must know where you can read and where you can't. This requires intimate knowledge of the [PE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) and how it is loaded in memory (here you need books).

Comment: umm thank you for answering, but I really don't think so. In fact, I have found some example code to dump strings that work perfectly, but It give me bytes instead of strings and also I have no idea to split them in rows like PH2 (https://github.com/ZaikoARG/PyDump).

Comment: @Karree the link you posted is for taking full memory dumps, which by the way, are taken by knowing the basic memory layout of processes in windows and linux (as in the answer). the script is dumping the **raw memory**, there is no concept of strings a new line

Comment: Yeah, then i don’t know how to put the strings in lines like PH2. That’ why i submit question, and also, that script dump bytes, not strings and not exactly what I need.